# How often is the Balestra and Quartata Used in Olympic or other fencing tournaments

Tags: competition, fencing

In this video [The Balestra and Quartata](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJsj5BBjNtg) two moderately advance pieces of fencing footwork are shown.

Are these still relevant in the Olympics and other Fencing tournaments or are they the remains of footwork used in earlier styles of fencing that have since become outdated.  (but are still taught for traditions sake).